# Leverage Google account credentials to send email in Android

Tags: android, email, smtp

Is it possible in Android to programmatically send an email using the phone's associated GMail credentials?  I can send an email when I explicitly provide the username and password, but I was hoping to leverage the Google account already associated with the phone.  Note that I don't need to actually access the username or password; I just want to leverage this information indirectly to send email.

Comment: I don't see why it would be an issue as long as the app presented the appropriate permission confirmation on installation.  The user would be fully aware of situations when an email would be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a project is underway that may support this functionality, though I have not yet had a chance to dig into it.  See the [google-authenticator-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator-for-android/).